# Trouble With Physics Joints [Gamemaker]

Tags: physics, game-maker, joints

I'm trying to create a series of physics-enabled 'ropes', with hard limits on how far they can swing left or right. They are comprised of an `oRopeRoot` kinematic physics object, which generates a certain number of `oRopeSections`, round little objects, and finally a single `oRopeEndSection`to cap it off.

These are connected by [revolute joints](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/physics/joints/physics_joint_revolute_create.html) with restricted angle of movements. Unfortunately, as you can see from [this gif](http://gph.is/2abDv7I?tc=1), they are all over the shop. I am still learning about physics joints in Gamemaker, and if anybody can look at the code below and see what might be wrong, I'd be very grateful for the learning experience.

**oRopeRoot**

Density: 0

Restitution: 0

Collision Group: -1

Linear Damping: 0.5

Angular Damping: 0.5

Friction: 1

(Kinematic)

*Create Event:*

```
depth = global.ForeignObjectsOnFaceLayer -1
OriginalX = x
OriginalY = y
image_alpha = 1
image_xscale = random_range(0.3,0.7)
image_yscale = image_xscale
GeneratedValues = true
RopeLength = irandom_range(20,30)
SectionsCreated = 0
EndCreated = false
ParentPore = noone
```

*Step Event:*

```
phy_position_x = OriginalX
phy_position_y = OriginalY - mLeftCheekFurArea.Difference


if SectionsCreated < (RopeLength - 1) {
CreateAndAttachSection()
SectionsCreated = SectionsCreated + 1
} else if SectionsCreated >= (RopeLength - 1) {
if EndCreated = false {
CreateAndAttachEndSection()
EndCreated = true
}
}
```

**CreateAndAttachSection()**

```
if SectionsCreated = 0 {

ParentSection = self.id
ChildSection = instance_create(ParentSection.x,ParentSection.y,oRopeSection)
physics_joint_revolute_create(ParentSection, ChildSection, ParentSection.x,ParentSection.y,-45,45,true,0,0,false,false)
ParentSection = ChildSection
ChildSection = noone

} else if SectionsCreated > 0 {
ChildSection = instance_create(ParentSection.x,ParentSection.y + 6,oRopeSection)
physics_joint_revolute_create(ParentSection, ChildSection, ParentSection.x, ParentSection.y + 6,-45,45,true,0,0,false, false)
ParentSection = ChildSection
ChildSection = noone
}
```

**CreateAndAttachEndSection**

```
ChildSection = instance_create(ParentSection.x,ParentSection.y + 6,oEndSection)
physics_joint_revolute_create(ParentSection, ChildSection, ParentSection.x, ParentSection.y + 6, -45, 45, true, 0, 0, false, false)
ParentSection = noone
ChildSection = noone
```

**oRopeSection**

Density: 1

Restitution: 0

Collision Group: -1

Linear Damping: 1

Angular Damping: 1

Friction: 1

**oEndSection**

Density: 1

Restitution: 0

Collision Group: -1

Linear Damping: 0.5

Angular Damping: 0.5

Friction: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have solved this myself. There were several problems with my specific approach which may be useful to others:

- The *pixels-to-meters* scale in my physics world (found in the Physics tab of the Room window) was set far, far too low. The default value is there for a reason: once I started using this, everything calmed down an awful lot.
- Setting a higher density for each component in the revolute joint (>= 1) also helped to calm the simulation down.

There is further illumination on this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/gamemaker/comments/4vyop8/help_using_prismatic_joints_and_textured/